# Update MySQL Query using substring of a value type in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am in need of a query that do something like this

```
UPDATE myTableName SET status = 0 WHERE type ( type contains last character = x)
```

E.g type values can be

```
ABCD9238
ADA323S
```

It needs to detect the second value.

Comment: Not clear from the given example what last char you will search ?\

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the last character S let's say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `right` function for this as

```
mysql>  select right('ABCD9238', 1);
+----------------------+
| right('ABCD9238', 1) |
+----------------------+
| 8                    |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select right('ADA323S', 1);
+---------------------+
| right('ADA323S', 1) |
+---------------------+
| S                   |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So if you are looking for last character to be `S` then you can use as

```
UPDATE myTableName SET status = 0 WHERE right(type,1) = 'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Substring function

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Second character from the end

```
UPDATE myTableName SET status = 0 WHERE substring(type,-2,1) = x
```

The last character

```
UPDATE myTableName SET status = 0 WHERE substring(type,-1) = x
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, you need to know if a character is in a column "type".

If so you can use LIKE statement.

```
UPDATE myTableName SET status = 0 WHERE type LIKE "%CHARACTER_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK%"
```

If the character is in the last position you should remove the last "%"

It can be used for strings, not only for char's.